# Unresponsive postgres prompt

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I installed PostgreSQL in Ubuntu 12.04, followed the usual steps and reached the 'postgres=#' prompt. Hereafter it is unresponsive to some commands. The commands like '\l' works but is totally unresponsive to commands like 'createuser' and 'createdb'. Did I miss to install some packages or simply what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read the error messages. Then include the error message(s) in the post. "Unresponsive" is vague and can mean several different things. However, the PG CLI will be quite clear about what it means. (Include a ";" to terminate the attempted command, if needed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`createuser` and `createdb` are *not* SQL statements, they are helper scripts. You don't run them in the Postgres command-line client (`psql`), you run them in your regular shell (e.g., in Bash).

Comment: Most likely the OP is also neglecting to either issue a \g to cause the sql query to execute commands, or terminating commands with a ; .